# In categorial logic, why do we need finite products to define the notion of "group," but not "monoid"?

Tags: category-theory

At n-lab ([link](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrine#idea)), it says that

> ...the theory of groups lives naturally in the doctrine of categories
>   with finite products, since a group object can be defined in any such
>   category. Likewise, the theory of monoids lives in the doctrine of
>   monoidal categories, and so on.

Why do we need finite products to define the notion of "group," but not "monoid"?

Comment: That's not entirely true. You could define "groups" within the doctrine of symmetric monoidal categories, but people prefer to call such a thing a Hopf algebra.

Comment: @Zhen: This is an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to define 'group object' in a monoidal category $(\Bbb A,\otimes,I)$ we could start out from a monoid $(A,\mu,\eta)$ (i.e. $\mu:A\otimes A\to A,\ \eta:I\to A$ with usual associativity and unit expressing diagrams) with an additional inverse operation $()^{-1}:A\to A$. But.. what should this inverse operation satisfy? When we want to translate the equations $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$ and $\ a^{-1}\cdot a=1$, we would need a *diagonal*-like map 
$$\Delta: A\to A\otimes A$$
 acting like "$a\mapsto(a,a)$", so the left hand side of the first equation which would act as "$a\mapsto a\cdot a^{-1}$" should be $\mu\circ \,\left({\rm id}_A\otimes()^{-1}\right)\,\circ\Delta$, and, by the way, for the right hand side "$a\mapsto 1$", we would need a map $\varepsilon:A\to I$ (which is automatically present and unique if $I$ is the *terminal object*). Thus, the first equation would translate to
$$ \mu\circ \,\left({\rm id}_A\otimes()^{-1}\right)\,\circ\Delta = \nu\circ\varepsilon\,.$$
Both $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$ are automatically present if $\otimes=\times$ (and thus $I$ is terminal).

However, as Zhen Lin commented, (if we assume a *comonoid* structure on $A$ with $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$, then) the translations of the two equations for the inverse define the notion of [*Hopf monoid*](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+monoid), where 'inverse' is renamed to '*antipode*'.